# I would like to scroll my CollectionViews both horizontal and vertical. Can't figure out how to do it

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a Gallery Page where I want to have 12 unique CollectionViews that scroll independently. This I can do, but I also want them to scroll vertically as a group. It seems like they need to be in a tableCell. But I can't seem to get this to work. I'm using Story Boards. So the question is how do you put the output of a CollectionView into a tableCell, with each tableRow holding a unique CollectionView.

This the trick to having collectionView swipe horizontal and independent. Each one is "tagged". Now I just need to go vertical too.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@">>> Entering %s <<<", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

if (cv.tag == 0) {
MyCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[flowerImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
cell.imageView.image = theImage;

return cell;
} else if (cv.tag == 1) {
MyCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL2" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[carImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
cell.imageView.image = theImage;

return cell;
} else {
MyCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL3" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[birdImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
cell.imageView.image = theImage;

return cell;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I ended up using Static Table Cells. Worked!